# is there any way to run a other function after a function run finish?

Tags: python

```
def foo():
    pass

def bar():
    print 'good bay'
```

two function like blow
and now i want to run bar function after foo run finish

is there some method like class use `__del__`?
as i know in class method i can use `__del__` like follow:

```
 class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __del__(self):
        bar()
```

but i can't use `foo.__del__`
is there any other method to do this ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question.

Comment: Please accept answers to your questions by clicking the check mark after them. This is your seventh question and you haven't accepted any answers.

Comment: @timger: Your question is very hard to understand. Your example using `__del__` does not make any sense. Can you please post a complete example that we can execute? Also, do you want `bar` to be executed also if `foo` throws an exception?

Comment: Can you provide a real-life example why you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what decorators are for. This decorator, used on `foo` with `bar` as an argument will will run `bar` after `foo` and still return `foo`s result. It will work on functions with any number of arguments.

```
def run_before(lastfunc, *args1, **kwargs1):
    def run(func):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                result = None
            finally:
                lastfunc(*args1, **kwargs1)
                return result
        return wrapped_func
    return run

def bar():
    print 'goodby'

@run_before(bar)
def foo():
    print "hello"

foo()
```

Edit: Added error handling. Thanks @Björn

Comment: This solution also does not run `foo` if `bar` raises an exception. Again, I am not sure if this is relevant, because the OPs question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
foo()
bar()
```

?

In case you want to have some general way to do it, you can try:

```
def run_after(f_after):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
            f_after()
            return ret
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

@run_after(bar)
def foo():
    ....
```

This way bar is always run after foo is executed.

Comment: Your solution does not execute `foo` if `bar` raises an exception. The question of the OP is very unclear, so I am not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: Well - it fails on exception, when bar is a generator, when bar doesn't exist / isn't a callable, etc. etc. This solution needs to be updated for whatever situation it's actually used in.

Comment: He's running `foo` before `bar` -- read it aloud. Your way sounds like "run after bar, foo" where mine reads as "run before bar, foo".. Also, your version doesn't allow `bar` to have arguments.

Comment: As above - since I don't know what OP intended, I didn't want to expand it too much.