# Call one function after another python, wrapping?

Tags: python, function, wrapper

I have two functions "a" and "b". "b" gets called when a user uploads a file. "b" renames the file and returns the new filename. After that the file is supposed to be edited. Like this:

```
def a():
    edits file
def b():
    renames file  
    return file
```

So if b happens and ends, a is supposed to happen. Once "b" returns file the function is over and nothing happens after. Exactly at this point I want "a" to happen, how is this possible? Right now I call "a" with a timer

```
t=Timer(1.0,a)
t.start()
```

but that's not a good solution. I tried with global variables but it doesn't work. I also tried `return file, a()` cause I thought then a would maybe get started. And finally wrapping it:

```
def b():
    global filename
    renames filename
    def a():
         edits filename  
    return filename
```

Is there something like `if b(): a()` ?

Anyone a suggestion?

Comment: Just call `a()` after you call `b()`. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: no, that doesn't work because a uses the global variable created in b and i I just call a after b it throws an error

Comment: Then you'll have to post something more specific, along the lines of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because that doesn't make any sense by itself.

Comment: @klausruprecht - check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604699/is-there-a-way-to-do-more-work-after-a-return-statement

Comment: Global variables are an anti-pattern.  Could you refactor `a` and `b` to take the filename as an argument?  That would likely make your solution simpler, at a minimum.

Comment: Does "a" edit the file or it's filename? (It does different things in your different examples). Answers are generally more useful if you post your actual code ;)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators), added by [PEP 0318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).  Some (complex) examples are in the [Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary).

```
def a():
    edits file

def call_a_after(f):
  def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
    ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
    a()
    return ret
  return decorate

@call_a_after
def b():
    renames file  
    return file
```

This wraps `b()` in `call_a_after()` (decorators are syntactic sugar for `b = call_a_after(b)`) letting you redifine, or decorate, what `b()` does.

Comment: yes, that's what I am looking for, however it doesn't work or I don't understand how decorators work. With your code a() is still called too early, because it throws an exception that file cannot be read

Comment: Since your `a()` and `b()` methods are only psuedocode, I can't tell you why your file cannot be read.  Perhaps `b()` failed to create the file?  As you can see in `call_a_after()`, the passed function `f` (in this case, `b`) finishes before `a()` is called, so if that isn't doing what you want, something else in your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
def a():
    #your code

def b():
    #your code
    a()
```

Example:

```
def first():
    print 'first'

def second():
    print 'second'
    first()

>>> second()
second
first
```

Comment: The issue is that he has a `return` at the end of `b`, so he can't just put other statements after it.

Comment: I tried that, however, this is not print but return

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7024300/6649086).

Using that, I think you might want something like this:

```
def run_before(lastfunc, *args1, **kwargs1):
    def run(func):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                result = None
            finally:
                lastfunc(*args1, **kwargs1)
                return result
        return wrapped_func
    return run

def a():
    edits file

@run_before(a)
def b():
    renames file  
    return file

b()
```

I think this question is confused further by the fact that you want b to run **before** a. For a more logical flow, I would suggest switching these around if possible.

All credit goes to [agf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf) for the original solution.