# Is there a way to run a function right after the __init__ of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```py
class SomeClass(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        ## Do something

        print('LOADED')

    @__init__.after_invoke #<-- Right here
    async def after_init(self, ctx):
        print('After')
```

I don't know how to do it, I tried many things but I can't really pick the `__init__` like a function to do something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024206/is-there-any-way-to-run-a-other-function-after-a-function-run-finish)

EDIT1:

What I want is an async method that is called because I'd like to interact with messages on discord right after the launch of the program

Comment: What exactly do you want this to do that can't be done in the `__init__` itself? Also, `ctx` comes from the invocation of the command, which happens well after the cog is initialized

Comment: Why doesn't ``__init__`` just call the method?

Comment: `__init__` can't call an async method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start executing Discord operations as soon as possible, you should add an [`on_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready) event listener to your cog.  When your bot logs into Discord and has prepared its internal caches, it will execute that event:

```
class SomeClass(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
         print("ONLINE")
         await some_coroutine()
```

Note that this may not be a perfect fit: if your bot has to reconnect for some reason, it will consider this a new session and execute `on_ready` again.  It would be pretty simple to add a variable to your cog to prevent this.

[You can similarly add an `on_message` event, commands, etc.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#cogs) just as you would a normal [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) bot

Comment: THANKS, I had just to add `self` in `on_ready` and it was all done !

Answer (score 2):

A decorator might be an overkill here. You can just call the method in `__init__`:

```
class SomeClass(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        print('LOADED')
        self.after_init(wherever_ctx_comes_from)    

    def after_init(self, ctx):
        print('After')
```

Comment: Tanks, but that method doesn't work with asynchronous functions...